# Data Dragon items, keyError

Tags: python, keyerror, riot-games-api

so ive run into a problem where i cant get acces to they key in riot json file.
http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.16.1/data/en_US/item.json this is official riot link which u can find on their riot api site under Items.

if you write this:

```
for key, value in items['data'].items():
    print(value)
```

it gives back all the values
If you write this:

```
for key value in items['data'].items():
    print(value['name'])
```

it gives back the name, and its like this with every other value[key] thing except for the 'depth key'. I used double for loop and it finally returned all the depth values:

```
for key,value in items['data'].items():
    for k,v in value.items():
        if k == 'depth':
            print(v)
```

But it doesnt save me cause i want to write something like, if the 'depth' == 3 i want to append the item 'name' into a list.
I thought that, maybe it is an erroe because the first items in this file doesnt have 'depth' key so i wrote an exception but it didnt work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `get()` method to get the value of specific key. Then you can compare it with the desired value. For your case, list comprehension with simple check could do the job:

```
names_list = [v.get('name') for v in items['data'].values() if v.get('depth') == 3]
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you so much <3 And the code is so short, you r a genius, thank you :D

Comment: @Midnightwhite3 If the answer helped, you should accept it and probably upvote.